esp modem library was not found
i was trying to compile for esp modem but ive run in to problems where i cant find the libraries dose someone know how to include these libraries...???
i'm using idf 5.2
list of not found libraries:
    #include "esp_modem_dce_service.h"
    #include "esp_modem.h"
    #include "esp_modem_dte.h"
    #include "esp_modem_netif.h"

ive tryed to include esp_modem in the cmake lists but it throws an error of configuration incomplete.

Espressif has a component registry where the less-common libraries live. According to the documentation of esp_modem you should add this component to your project using:
idf.py add-dependency "espressif/esp_modem^1.1.0"


i've already added these dependencies but they are not compiling with the code...

Then you need to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example of your project, otherwise we can't help you further.
